# Read data from csv file and pass the values into sql statment using python

Tags: python, sql, csv

```
seqno   soursequery targetquery
1   select count(*) from table  select count(*) from table
2   select count(*) from table  select count(*) from table
```

I have csv file like above and I have to read `seqno` and both queries and compare the result in Python. I have to put the testcase status in the same file.

Expected:
if `seqno` is 1 I have to read first two queries(source and target) and compare the count of both queries.

Thanks,
in advance

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this.

```
# Select All From CSV File Where

import csv
# Asks for search criteria from user
search_parts = input("Enter search criteria:\n").split(",")
# Opens csv data file
file = csv.reader(open("C:\\your_path_here\\test.csv"))
# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.
for row in file:
    if all([x in row for x in search_parts]):
        print(row)
```

Comment: Actually i want to read first row from file and i have to compare the count of the two tables...